# Rails 3 private message plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, private, message

Maybe someone knows a good plugin for private messages? I'm using Rails 3 and Devise as a plug-in for authorization. On github, I found only this [plugin](https://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages), but after installing I get the message: undefined local variable or method `has_private_messages'... While in Rails console I can send messages... I would be grateful for any help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restart your Server. They plugin may not have loaded.